# insert into with two variables php

Tags: php, pdo

The below inserts one variable just fine. But how do you do two?

```
 $query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `{$test}` (user_id) VALUES (?)");
 $query->bindValue(1, $idv);
```

I've tried

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `{$test}` (user_id,another_id) VALUES (?,?)");
$query->bindValue(1, $idv);
$query->bindValue(1, $idvsecond);
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I was just going to say that: Try `$query->bindValue(2, $idvsecond);` but the Night crew just kicked in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
$query->bindValue(1, $idvsecond);
```

with

```
$query->bindValue(2, $idvsecond);
              //  ^--------- Since you are adding a second parameter , just make this as 2
```

Comment: Ah that would make sense wouldn't it.

Answer (score 0):

For each parameter you want to bind, give it its corresponding number:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `{$test}` (user_id,another_id) VALUES (?,?)");
$query->bindValue(1, $idv);
$query->bindValue(2, $idvsecond);
```